# Disable Multiple Specific Options in Select Lists that have same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my create form, I have 3 select lists that all have the same values.  However, the same option cannot be selected for more than one select.  So, if I select option one in the first select.. then I shouldn't be able to select that option in the other two.

I almost have it, but I'm running into an issue where if I select an option then the disabling works for the other two, but as soon as I select an option for the 2nd select, then the option that I selected in the first select becomes active again for the options in the third select.

Here is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<select id="Person-One-Select" class="person-select">
  <option value="">-- Select Person One --</option>
  <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
  <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
  <option value="Babe Ruth">Babe Ruth</option>
  <option value="Ted Williams">Ted Williams</option>
  <option value="Pete Rose">Pete Rose</option>
</select>

<select id="Person-Two-Select" class="person-select">
  <option value="">-- Select Person Two --</option>
  <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
  <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
  <option value="Babe Ruth">Babe Ruth</option>
  <option value="Ted Williams">Ted Williams</option>
  <option value="Pete Rose">Pete Rose</option>
</select>

<select id="Person-Three-Select" class="person-select">
  <option value="">-- Select Person Three --</option>
  <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
  <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
  <option value="Babe Ruth">Babe Ruth</option>
  <option value="Ted Williams">Ted Williams</option>
  <option value="Pete Rose">Pete Rose</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Get value of Person Select on change
$(".person-select").change(function() {

    // reset all value to be active
    $(".person-select option").prop("disabled", false);

    // get value
    var selectedPerson = $(this).val();

    // look for value in 2nd and 3rd selects and disable them
    if (selectedPerson !== "") {
        $(".person-select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

});


});
```

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyb12/jkx2awc9/1/) to show a working example.

Comment: so you want to disable any value already selected on all potential select-boxes apart from the select-box that holds that value?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Correct.  If I pick John Doe in Select One.. then I shouldn't be able to select John Doe in select two or three and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
    $(".person-select option").prop("disabled", false);
```

It is undoing previously-disabled options when you select from the next drop down. Then, you disable only the options with the name value in the selected drop down, effectively undoing previous drop-down selection disabling.

What you should do is check ALL of the drop downs when one is clicked, undo disable on all, and then re-disable all options based on currently-selected names from all drop downs. So this:

```
    // Get value of Person Select on change
$(".person-select").change(function() {

    //Select all drop downs
    var all_selects = $(".person-select");
    $(".person-select option").prop("disabled", false); //Activate all, but we will redisable appropriate ones next.

    //Recurse. Look at each drop down, and then compare against all drop downs that exist.
    for(var x = 0; x < all_selects.length; x++) {

        //Get selected name from each drop down, and then compare it against all drop downs, so that we can disable an option with the same value in other dropdowns.
        var currentSelection = $(all_selects[x]).prop("id");
        for(var y = 0; y < all_selects.length; y++) {

           //Ignore self. We do not want to disable the option with the above currentSelection value within that dropwdown, as it will prevent form submission of the selected value.
           if(currentSelection == $(all_selects[y]).prop("id")) continue;

           //Now, disable duplicate options in OTHER drop downs.
           var selectedPerson = $(all_selects[x]).val();
           if (selectedPerson !== "") {

               $(all_selects[y]).find("option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled","disabled");

           }

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Okay, so there might be another issue concerning this.  The first select option is required, and the form is not submitting because the value they're selecting is becoming disabled.

Comment: Got it. Editing my response. Should be a simple fix.

Comment: Just posted a question about it, if you want to answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363482/only-disable-option-in-other-selects-but-not-the-one-where-the-option-is-select

Comment: I would suggest removing an extra question about this. Most Stackoverflow moderators will try to close that anyway. But I added the fix above. Notice the "continue" statement. This will prevent the dropdown that has a selected value from disabling that option within the same dropdown.

Comment: I have it in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyb12/o7hj4f15/).  It is partially working.  Even though the 2nd and 3rd selects are not required, they will be used and need to be submitted with the form as well.  Also, if I choose "John Doe" in the first select, I can still select him in the 2nd

Comment: For clarity, if I choose `John Doe` in the first select, then `John Doe` should be disabled only in the 2nd and 3rd selects, and vice versa.  `John Doe` should not be disabled in the select where he was chosen.

Comment: Simple mistake on my part. Fixed. `var selected_person = $(all_selected[x]).val();` should be `var selected_person = $(this).val();` I apologize as I didn't verify in the Fiddle last time. EDIT: Actually this is closer, but not perfect. Making another fix now!

Comment: We are getting there lol.  With your most recent edit, it is disabling the option in the original select, but I know why.  In the last `if` statement, we are disabling the option for all selects with the class name `.person-select`.  Is there like an `except` method?  Like... disable the option in all selects **except** the one where the option was chosen? What about `not()`

Comment: Got it this time. We needed to recurse. For each drop down, iterate through all (ignoring self), and disable matching option. The above method works exactly as I expect. I select Jane Doe in select #1, she is disabled in #2 and #3. If I select another drop down, the same is true in the other drop downs. No one gets disabled in their own drop down, however. And you can change the same dropdown to a new person, and it all behaves as expected.

Comment: Sorry, still disabling on my end. Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyb12/o7hj4f15/13/)

Comment: Sorry, I am just silly. I am really sorry for the run around. Copy the above one more time. Made one more edit. And it seems to work now. I know I've said that the last 5 times. Give it one more try.

Comment: Hahaha no problem.  I have the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/troyb12/o7hj4f15/16/) with what I think is your last edit.  It's disabling the option in the original dropdown but not disabling it in the others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190718/discussion-between-asyranok-and-m12-bennett).

Answer (score 0):

try this for your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Get value of Person Select on change
$(".person-select").change(function() {

    var slctID = $(this).attr('id');

    // reset all value to be active
    $(".person-select option").prop("disabled", false);

    // get value
    var selectedPerson = $(this).val();

    switch(slctID) {
    case "Person-One-Select":
        if (selectedPerson !== "") {
        $("#Person-Two-Select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#Person-Three-Select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        break;
    case "Person-Two-Select":
        if (selectedPerson !== "") {
        $("#Person-One-Select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#Person-Three-Select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        break;
    case "Person-Three-Select":
        if (selectedPerson !== "") {
        $("#Person-One-Select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#Person-Two-Select option[value='" + selectedPerson + "']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        break;
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we keep track of a currently chosen values Array and reference all the options against it and if the value of the options match then they are disabled (negating the relative selects' chosen option.)

```js
const selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select.person-select')

let chosen = []

const _disableRelated = () => {
  const options = []
  selectBoxes
  .forEach(select => {
    const unselectedOpts = [...select.querySelectorAll('option')].filter(o => o.value !== select.value)
    options.push(...unselectedOpts)
  })
  
  options.forEach(option => {
    const action = chosen.indexOf(option.value) !== -1 ? 'setAttribute' : 'removeAttribute'
    
    option[action]('disabled', null)
  })
}

const _handleChange = e => {  
  const { value  } = e.target
  
  chosen.length = 0
  selectBoxes.forEach(({ value }) => value ? chosen.push(value) : null)
  
  _disableRelated()
}

selectBoxes.forEach(select => select.addEventListener('change', _handleChange))
```

```html
<select id="Person-One-Select" class="person-select">
  <option value="">-- Select Person One --</option>
  <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
  <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
  <option value="Babe Ruth">Babe Ruth</option>
  <option value="Ted Williams">Ted Williams</option>
  <option value="Pete Rose">Pete Rose</option>
</select>

<select id="Person-Two-Select" class="person-select">
  <option value="">-- Select Person Two --</option>
  <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
  <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
  <option value="Babe Ruth">Babe Ruth</option>
  <option value="Ted Williams">Ted Williams</option>
  <option value="Pete Rose">Pete Rose</option>
</select>

<select id="Person-Three-Select" class="person-select">
  <option value="">-- Select Person Three --</option>
  <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
  <option value="Jane Doe">Jane Doe</option>
  <option value="Babe Ruth">Babe Ruth</option>
  <option value="Ted Williams">Ted Williams</option>
  <option value="Pete Rose">Pete Rose</option>
</select>
```